# ILP in poly-time?

Tags: algorithm, integer-programming, np-hard

Integer programming is said to be NP-complete. However, I think formulating a problem into ILP can't prove the problem to be NP-hard. Is there any example of problem that can be modeled into ILP but has a polynomial time?

Comment: Maximum flow seems to fit the bill?

Comment: Find the maximum of a list of numbers? But formulating a problem as an ILP shows it's NP, not NP hard.

Comment: There's a confusion here. "Formulating a problem as a particular instance of ILP" means you've shown that your problem is **not harder than** ILP. Just because we don't have an algorithm to solve **all ILP problems** in polynomial time, doesn't mean that **your particular problem** cannot be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: (I apologize for the triple-negation in my previous comment)

Comment: Sorry I just found out I have a typo. I meant I think formulating a problem into ILP can't prove the problem to be NP-hard.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Could you explain more? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: [Maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) is one of the harder-looking "easy" (i.e., in P) problems that you can model with ILP.